# DiscordAPIError: Interaction has already been acknowledged. Discord.js react() function problem

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have this poll command that creates a new MessageEmbed, and then I want the bot to react to the votes with 4 emotes, to be able to vote in the poll. The problem is when I use the `reply()` function with an interaction the bot crashes and gives me this error: `DiscordAPIError: Interaction has already been acknowledged.` I tried to fetch the reply but it doesn't seem to work. Here's the code:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('poll')
        .setDescription('Make a poll, (and you get to choose the options) ;)')
        .addStringOption((option) =>
            option
                .setName('title')
                .setDescription('The title of the poll embed.')
                .setRequired(true)
        )
        .addStringOption((option) => 
            option
                .setName('option1')
                .setDescription('1st option for the poll.')
                .setRequired(true)
        )
        .addStringOption((option) => 
            option
                .setName('option2')
                .setDescription('2nd option for the poll.')
                .setRequired(true)
        )
        .addStringOption((option) =>
            option
                .setName('option3')
                .setDescription('3rd option for the poll.')
                .setRequired(false)
        )
        .addStringOption((option) =>
            option
                .setName('option4')
                .setDescription('4th option for the poll.')
                .setRequired(false)
        )

    async execute(client, interaction, Discord) {
        let pollEmbed;

        if (interaction.options.get('option3') && interaction.options.get('option4')) {
            pollEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('RANDOM')
                .setTitle(interaction.options.get('title').value)
                .setAuthor(`Poll by: ${interaction.user.username}`)
                .setDescription(
                    `:regional_indicator_a: - ${interaction.options.get('option1').value}\n
                    :regional_indicator_b: - ${interaction.options.get('option2').value}\n
                    :regional_indicator_c: - ${interaction.options.get('option3').value}\n
                    :regional_indicator_d: - ${interaction.options.get('option4').value}`
                )
                .setTimestamp();
        }

        if (!interaction.options.get('option3') && !interaction.options.get('option4')) {
            pollEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('RANDOM')
                .setTitle(interaction.options.get('title').value)
                .setAuthor(`Poll by: ${interaction.user.username}`)
                .setDescription(
                    `:regional_indicator_a: - ${interaction.options.get('option1').value}\n
                    :regional_indicator_b: - ${interaction.options.get('option2').value}\n`
                )
                .setTimestamp();
        }

        if (interaction.options.get('option3') && !interaction.options.get('option4')) {
            pollEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('RANDOM')
                .setTitle(interaction.options.get('title').value)
                .setAuthor(`Poll by: ${interaction.user.username}`)
                .setDescription(
                    `:regional_indicator_a: - ${interaction.options.get('option1').value}\n
                    :regional_indicator_b: - ${interaction.options.get('option2').value}\n
                    :regional_indicator_c: - ${interaction.options.get('option3').value}\n`
                )
                .setTimestamp();
        }

        if (!interaction.options.get('option3') && interaction.options.get('option4'))
            return interaction.reply('You have to put option 3 before option 4!');

        message = interaction.reply({ embeds: [pollEmbed], fetchReply: true });

        await message.react(':regional_indicator_a:');
        await message.react(':regional_indicator_b:');
        await message.react(':regional_indicator_c:');
        await message.react(':regional_indicator_d:');
    }
};
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to `await` your `interaction.reply`.

It should be

```js
message = await interaction.reply({ embeds: [pollEmbed], fetchReply: true });
```

Comment: Omg I'm so dumb, thank you!

Answer (score 30):

Just leaving this reply here for future reference, another issue that might cause `DiscordAPIError: Interaction has already been acknowledged` is if you have two instances of your bot running simultaneously, for example on a remote server somewhere and on your local development server.