# DiscordAPIError[40060]: Interaction has already been acknowledged | Error with embeds and buttons

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have this discord.js embed with buttons where users can choose an attack move and it will attack a boss. The problem starts when I defeat the boss. When I defeat the boss and want to run the command again, it sends the embed, but when I try to interact with the buttons, it returns with a `DiscordAPIError[40060]: Interaction has already been acknowledged.` error and it goes back to the previous embed data.

I think it might have to do with the `const collector interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector();`  or the `collector.on('end', collected => console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`));` code, but I'm not sure.

Yes, I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71119936/discordapierror-interaction-has-already-been-acknowledged-discord-js-react-f) but this does not answer my question unless I'm just stupid.

Here's the code:

```
const { ApplicationCommandType, EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const { ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, Events } = require('discord.js');
const wait = require('node:timers/promises').setTimeout;
const fs = require('fs');

const User = require("../../models/user");
planetsJson = require("../../json/planetsv2.json")
bossesJson = require("../../json/bosses.json")

module.exports = {
  name: 'dungeon',
  description: "Check yours or someone elses balance",
  type: ApplicationCommandType.ChatInput,
  run: async (client, interaction, args) => {

    const userid = interaction.user.id
    let user = await User.findOne({
      ID: userid
    });



    const eArmor = user.Equipped.Armor
    const eWeapon = user.Equipped.Weapon
    let userHealth = user.Health

    let rawdataBoss = fs.readFileSync('json/bosses.json');
    let boss = JSON.parse(rawdataBoss);

    let rawdataPlanets = fs.readFileSync('json/planetsv2.json');
    let planets = JSON.parse(rawdataPlanets);

    let planetName = planets.planets[user.Planet]
    let cityName = planets[planetName].cities[user.City]
    let bossName = planets[planetName].bosses[user.City]
    console.log(bossName)

    let bossHealth = boss[bossName].health;

    const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
      .addComponents(
        new ButtonBuilder()
          .setCustomId('attack1')
          .setLabel(user.Inventory[eWeapon].Attacks[0].name)
          .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary),

        new ButtonBuilder()
          .setCustomId('attack2')
          .setLabel(user.Inventory[eWeapon].Attacks[1].name)
          .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary),

        /*new ButtonBuilder()
          .setCustomId('attack3')
          .setLabel(user.Inventory[eWeapon].Attacks[2].name)
          .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary),*/

        /*new ButtonBuilder()
          .setCustomId('block')
          .setLabel("Block (1)") (the 3 indiciates how many blocks he has left. the default is 1. increase it by buying upgrades)
          .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary),*/
      );

      let bossDamageArray0 = boss[bossName].damage
      let bossDamage0 = Math.floor(Math.random() * bossDamageArray0.length);
      let bossDamage = bossDamageArray0[bossDamage0]

    const embeds = {
      color: 0x0099FF,
      title: `kwm vs ${bossName}`,
      fields: [
        { name: `${bossName}'s Health`, value: bossHealth, inline: true }, 
        { name: `${interaction.user.tag}`, value: `${userHealth}`, inline: true }, 
        { name: '\u200B', value: 'What will you do?'}
      ]
    }


    await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embeds], components: [row], ephemeral: true });


    const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector();


    collector.on('collect', async i => {
      if (i.customId === 'attack1') {

        row.components[0].setDisabled(true)
        row.components[1].setDisabled(true)

        await i.deferUpdate();

        let userDamageArray0 = user.Inventory[eWeapon].Attacks[0].damage
        let userDamage0 = Math.floor(Math.random() * userDamageArray0.length);
        let userDamage = userDamageArray0[userDamage0]; // users damage

       // console.log(boss)

        //let bossName = planets[planetName].bosses[user.City]

        bossHealth = bossHealth - userDamage
        embeds.fields = [
        { name: `${bossName}'s Health`, value: bossHealth, inline: true }, 
        { name: `${interaction.user.tag}`, value: `${userHealth}`, inline: true }, 
        { name: `\u200B`, value: ` ` },
        { name: `You dealt ${userDamage} to ${bossName} using ${user.Inventory[eWeapon].Attacks[1].name}!`, value: `${bossName} is now attacking...` }]

        if (bossHealth <= 0) {
          row.components[0].setDisabled(true)
          row.components[1].setDisabled(true)
          if (user.City + 1 === 5) {
            user.Planet = user.Planet + 1
            user.City = 0
            user.save()
            console.log(user.Planet + " planet")
          } else {
            user.City = user.City + 1
            user.save()
            console.log(user.City + " city")
          }

          embeds.fields = [{ name: `\u200B`, value: `You killed ${bossName}!` }]
          return i.editReply({ embeds: [embeds]})

          // increase the city number by 1; if it reaches 5, then increase the planet number by 1
        }   

        await i.editReply({ embeds: [embeds], components: [row], ephemeral: true })

        await wait(3000);

        // -----------------------------------------------
        
        userHealth = userHealth - bossDamage
        embeds.fields = [
          { name: `${bossName}'s Health`, value: bossHealth, inline: true }, 
          { name: `${interaction.user.tag}`, value: `${userHealth}`, inline: true }, 
          { name: `\u200B`, value: ` ` },
          { name: `${bossName} dealt ${bossDamage} to ${interaction.user.tag}!`, value: `It is now your turn to attack!` }]

          if (userHealth <= 0) {
            row.components[0].setDisabled(true)
            row.components[1].setDisabled(true)
            embeds.fields = [{ name: `\u200B`, value: `${bossName} has killed you!` }]
            return i.editReply({ embeds: [embeds]})
          }

          row.components[0].setDisabled(false)
          row.components[1].setDisabled(false)
  
          await i.editReply({ embeds: [embeds], components: [row], ephemeral: true })
      }
    });

    collector.on('collect', async i => {
      if (i.customId === 'attack2') {
        row.components[0].setDisabled(true)
        row.components[1].setDisabled(true)

        await i.deferUpdate();

        let userDamageArray1 = user.Inventory[eWeapon].Attacks[1].damage
        let userDamage1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * userDamageArray1.length);
        let userDamage = userDamageArray1[userDamage1]; // users damage

        bossHealth = bossHealth - userDamage
        embeds.fields = [
        { name: `${bossName}'s Health`, value: bossHealth, inline: true }, 
        { name: `${interaction.user.tag}`, value: `${userHealth}`, inline: true }, 
        { name: `\u200B`, value: ` ` },
        { name: `You dealt ${userDamage} to ${bossName} using ${user.Inventory[eWeapon].Attacks[1].name}!`, value: `${bossName} is now attacking...` }]

        if (bossHealth <= 0) {
          row.components[0].setDisabled(true)
          row.components[1].setDisabled(true)
          embeds.fields = [{ name: `\u200B`, value: `You killed ${bossName}!` }]
          return i.editReply({ embeds: [embeds]})
        }

        

        await i.editReply({ embeds: [embeds], components: [row], ephemeral: true })

        await wait(3000);

        // -----------------------------------------------
        
        userHealth = userHealth - bossDamage
        embeds.fields = [
          { name: `${bossName}'s Health`, value: bossHealth, inline: true }, 
          { name: `${interaction.user.tag}`, value: `${userHealth}`, inline: true }, 
          { name: `\u200B`, value: ` ` },
          { name: `${bossName} dealt ${bossDamage} to ${interaction.user.tag}!`, value: `It is now your turn to attack!` }]


          if (userHealth <= 0) {
            row.components[0].setDisabled(true)
            row.components[1].setDisabled(true)
            embeds.fields = [{ name: `\u200B`, value: `${bossName} has killed you!` }]
            return i.editReply({ embeds: [embeds]})
          }

          row.components[0].setDisabled(false)
          row.components[1].setDisabled(false)
  
          await i.editReply({ embeds: [embeds], components: [row], ephemeral: true })
      }
    });

    collector.on('end', collected => console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`));

  }
};
```

Entire error:

```
throw new DiscordAPIError(data, "code" in data ? data.code : data.error, status, method, url, requestData);
              ^

DiscordAPIError[40060]: Interaction has already been acknowledged.
    at SequentialHandler.runRequest (D:\Auntham\node_modules\discord.js\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:667:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (D:\Auntham\node_modules\discord.js\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:464:14)
    at async REST.request (D:\Auntham\node_modules\discord.js\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:910:22)
    at async ButtonInteraction.deferUpdate (D:\Auntham\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:200:5)
    at async InteractionCollector.<anonymous> (D:\Auntham\slashCommands\battle\test2.js:92:9) {
  requestBody: { files: undefined, json: { type: 6 } },
  rawError: {
    message: 'Interaction has already been acknowledged.',
    code: 40060
  },
  code: 40060,
  status: 400,
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/interactions/1081036886837051453/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTA4MTAzNjg4NjgzNzA1MTQ1Mzo3N01IcWhzVXZDTjZVZDVtaGdLaEc5SGF2VWY5TUZUZ0VISFppaGY1V3hPVkppdTBlWFI5TElwQ2pMb3YyeFB0RDRFdjhuckRvRHRnUVM3NHRUYXJxN2VHa1lFdjkydmswUXprYURZOXlyTm1GaHRya09uM1ZucHdka2RCRWI2Sg/callback'
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to use only one `client.on("collect", ...)` event handler? I think because you have to "collect" handlers the event might emit the "end" event twice.
Edit: Looking at other similar cases, you may wann try adding await statements before your replies (e.g. `return await i.editReply({ embeds: [embeds]})`), you are missing a few ones.

Comment: @Daerendor - I tried using only one client.on("collect"), ... but the buttons weren't functioning as they were when using two client.on's and the same error occurred. I also added "return await i.editReply(...)" to the ones that were missing and the error still showed up.